# Excel 2013 spreadsheet is too slow

Tags: windows-xp, microsoft-excel-2013

I was upgraded to Excel 2013 on my XP machine after a hard drive replacement.  Now, when entering or changing a value in a cell, it takes 3 or 4 minutes for the change to ripple through the cells and formulas.  In Excel 2010, when you changed an amount in a cell, it only took seconds for the same sheet to refresh.

What has happened, how can it be resolved? Is there a setting in Excel 2013 to make that sheet faster?

Comment: Presumably this is a huge spreadsheet?

Comment: Do you have auto-calculations on? Are there any macros? Does it happen with every sheet? What about different computers? Etc.

Comment: it happens on all of my spreadsheets.  My hard drive was recently replaced and Microsoft Office 2013 was placed on it, so this is fairly new to me.

Comment: Yes the Automatic Calculation is on

Comment: Have you tried disabling "hardware graphics acceleration" in the Advanced Options?

Comment: Yes I already tried that one

Comment: A few things. You are running XP. No longer supported and likely not tuned to work with Excel 2013. Are you running the 64-bit version of Excel 2013? That could cause issues as XP doesn't support 64-bit anything. You got a new hard drive: fewer RPM? More RPM and not compatible with XP? Does anyone else have the same issues with the file? Especially with a similar software setup?

Comment: Okay I found the answer... if you goto Options under Excel, click on Formulas... you have to check the Enable Iterative Calculation... then hit okay... this will make your entries enter right away

Comment: @KimCopeland You should create an actual answer and put what you've found into it. You're allowed (encouraged actually) to answer your own questions. :)

Answer (score 3):

`File | Options | Formulas | Calculation | Manual` will turn off automatic recalculation. When you need a recalc, press {F9} or {Control-Equal}. It will still be slow, but at least it will be slow less often.

Also, a different approach might allow you to re-enable automatic recalculations. 
`Click on the Excel button at upper left then the Excel Options button at lower right | Formulas in left side pane | Enable iterative calculation | OK` . Thanks to Kim Copeland for that suggestion.

Let's also consider you have XP (which does not meet [Microsoft's System Requirements](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee624351.aspx) for Excel 2013), so there's no multi-threading, and Excel 2013 assumes you *will* have a machine with multi-threading; [code bloat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_bloat) is inevitable, and every new version of Microsoft apps assumes you have a better computer.

Comment: Okay I found the answer... if you goto Options under Excel, click on Formulas... you have to check the Enable Iterative Calculation... then hit okay... this will make your entries enter right away

Answer (score 0):

Try this [link](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-control-formula-recalculation-in-excel-2013.html) and the suggestion on it.

It says:

> To control when Excel calculates your worksheet, you click the
>   Calculation Options button on the Formulas tab of the Ribbon and then
>   click the Manual option button or press Alt+MXM. After switching to
>   manual recalculation, when you make a change in a value, formula, or
>   name that would usually cause Excel to recalculate the worksheet, the
>   program displays the message “Calculate” on the status bar.

Do not be offended. I think the "Dummies" series of books are extremely useful.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. 
Please take a look here too: http://superuser.com/help/deleted-answers

Comment: Okay I found the answer... if you goto Options under Excel, click on Formulas... you have to check the Enable Iterative Calculation... then hit okay... this will make your entries enter right away

Comment: Don't know anyone in IT whom I work with who doesn;t have at least three Dummies books.

Answer (score 0):

Original Poster provided answer in comments of other posts:

> Okay I found the answer... if you goto Options under Excel, click on Formulas... you have to check the Enable Iterative Calculation... then hit okay... this will make your entries enter right away –  Kim Copeland Feb 20 at 20:22